# Is there a comprehensive algebra exercises site online?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, online-resources

I'm trying to find a place that has guided walkthroughs/answer guides for intermediate algebra, college algebra, and precalc.  Maybe trig, also.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found good results at www.khanacademy.org.  You can sign up for an account, watch tutorials, practice exercises in a pedagogical order, and track your progress.  Another site that has a lot of good walkthroughs is www.patrickjmt.com, but without the exercises.  Best wishes.

Comment: Great.  It seems to be free, too.  Sorry, but I can't accept for 6 minutes.  Maybe we'll get another good site. :D

Comment: It's fun. :)  Thank you.

Comment: I really need to do that, too.  As I got into Calculus 3, I realized my ability with Algebra was declining rapidly.  I was still pretty good with Trig, though.  Now, I'm out of practice with Trig as well.  I feel like I don't have time to plan lessons for myself, and I hope that these sites will keep my mind up to date, as I study new things, like programming.

Comment: I agree with you, @FreeTrader. Although we must be happy with what there is!

Answer (score 1):

I think Art of Problem Solving is a good place to get several Questions on algebra or what ever topic you want in various levels of difficulties.
Art of Problem Solving Website : http://www.artofproblemsolving.com

Comment: its a forum and doesnt help in a defined structure

Comment: But one can learn a lot from that website that's why I  suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

[dzdx.xyz](https://www.dzdx.xyz) contains algebra exercises on

- factorization of polynomials
- simplification of rational fractions and expression with radicals
- logarithmic identities

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through a book titled "The Humongous Book of Algebra Problems". It primarily covers Alegbra I and II. Over 1,000 problems to work through. So far I've found it quite good.